# /bin/sh: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nginx, mysql

In my web server running with following architecture

```
Centos 6.5 
Plesk 12
Nginx 1.6 (As a reverse proxy)
Apache 2.2 
MySQL 5.5
PHP 5.5
Openfire 1.9.4
Pagespeed
```

web server can have max 500 concurrent users at a time but is quite powerful with

```
CPU: Intel® Xeon® E3-1225v3 (Quad-Core, 4x 3.6 GHz)
Memory: 24GB
```

i get this following error frequently,

```
/bin/sh: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

I suspect one of these above module is having memory leak, but when i search/googled i dont find any wide known issues of memory leaks of these.

And when this happens its locks down the shell, also Websites display 502,504

but i cant do a

```
ps -aux
```

or any command to find-out which process is causing the issue Because shell it self is also stucked and not responding

After 5-10 mins all things get back to normal it self. and ps -aux doesn't show any process invalid/heavy

- How may i fix or find out which is causing these outages ? *
- Can i run applications in a limited memory mode ? if so how *
- What system logs may be helpful to determine the cause of the issue ? *
- How to do a memory check via cron job and see if its going out restart or do some thing to prevent it ? *

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is apache.  Check your max servers setting. Also look for the section about max workers (not in front of a computer right now so I cant give you the exact setting).

Run ps aux | grep httpd | wc -l.   Youll also want to do this without the wc to see how much memory each process is using.

First question should be, do you have enouch memory?

Run free -m to check.

Comment: problem is i cant run any of these commands like " free -m " when this is happening as shell gets stucked.. when its returned to normal memory looks ok with over 3-4 GB still free..